# Export state_dict checkpoint from .pt model PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, state-dict

I'm new to PyTorch and the whole model/AI programming.

I have a library that needs a checkpoint in the form of a *state_dict* from a model to run.

I've the `.pt` model (more preciously the [radtts pre-trained model](https://github.com/NVIDIA/radtts)) and I need to extract the dictionary for the checkpoint.

From what I understand from the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#save-load-state-dict-recommended) I should be able to load the model and save the *state_dict* with `torch.save(model.state_dict(), PATH)`

My problem is, first of all, is it correct? How do I load the model on PyTorch to extract the *state_dict*?

Answer (score 1):

If you load the checkpoint you linked to (`hifigan_libritts100360_generator0p5.pt`) then you will see that the archive contains a single key/value pair: `"generator"` and is assigned to the state dictionary of the checkpoint itself.

```
>>> pt = torch.load('hifigan_libritts100360_generator0p5.pt')
>>> pt.keys()
dict_keys(['generator'])
```

Comment: So I'll probably miss something regarding the denomination of things. The *.pt* file is the "checkpoint" or the "model"?

Comment: What do you mean by "model" exactly? This pt file contains the weights of the model checkpoint.